# Why is my foreign key association not yielding results?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I have two models in my rails app, `Appointment` and `Policy`.  My Appointment model `has_many :policies, class_name: "Policy", foreign_key: 'writing_code'` and my Policy model `belongs_to :appointment`.  The `writing_code` column in each table is a String.

While it would appear that the association has been made (my app runs), `@appointment.policies` yields no results.  Can someone shed some light on where I've gone wrong here?

Also, to preemptively answer the obvious question, I cannot simply use `appointment_id` because I will be uploading policy data that has an appointment's (or user's) "writing code" associated to each record.  The data will not include the appointment id since it comes from a separate, third party system.

Thanks in advance for all your help!

EDIT:

schema:

```
create_table "policies", :force => true do |t| 
t.integer "product_id" 
t.decimal "premium" 
t.string "writing_code" 
t.datetime "created_at", :null => false t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false end`
```

Comment: what you mean by `yields no results`? are you getting `nil` error? have you added `policy_id` to `appointments` table?

Comment: I get no errors.. the result is [].  Why do I need to add `policy_id` here when I'm associating via the `writing_code` column?

Comment: so the `writing_code` is the foreign key. I overlooked that. what you are getting is an empty array. and you think it should not be empty? try it in the console. verify if you really should have Apointment and Policy objects that are associated

Comment: I get an empty array in the console as well :(

Comment: Take a look at the sql generated in the logs.  Then take that sql string and try it in your db console.  It will return no results there as well but you may be able to debug the issue.  It could be data related which will be easier to see.

Comment: Great suggestion @Swards.. even though my writing_code is 12345, the generated sql looks like this:  SELECT "policies".* FROM "policies" WHERE "policies"."writing_code" = 2.  Not sure exactly why this is happening other than the model association is still trying to associate via the policy_id

Comment: How are you going with this?

Answer (score 1):

I think here is your problem:

You have:

```
class Appointment 
  has_many :policies, class_name: "Policy", foreign_key: 'writing_code'
end
```

Here is what the [guides says](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

"By convention, Rails assumes that the column used to hold the foreign key on this model is the name of the association with the suffix _id added."

Here is an example from the guides:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :customer, class_name: "Patron",
                    foreign_key: "patron_id"
end
```

In your case, your `class` name is `Policy` but your `foreign_key` name is `writing_code`. which is not conventional.

Answer (score 1):

Rails is very opinionated. Stay within the way rails likes to work and life gets much easier. 
I Agree completely with @WaliAli said also.

"@appointment.policies yields no results"

For appointment to have many policies, each policy needs to be linked with an appointment, in the Model AND in the the table schema.

What this means is that policies should have a field 'appointment_id' which is an integer.

Add an appointment_id field to the policies table.

```
$ rails generate migration AddAppointmentIdToPolicies appointment_id:integer
$ rake db:migrate
```

Then you do the following:

```
class Policy
  has_many :appointments     # this lets you do @policy.appointments
end

class Appointment
  belongs_to :policy         # this lets you do @appointment.policy
end
```

For 99% of rails apps doing it another way, whereby has_many & belongs_to includes more optional paramaters is a code smell.

**[Update 1:]**

> *"I have policy data that will be uploaded from a legacy system via .csv
>   file. This data will have no knowledge of the appointment_id, which is
>   why I need to use the writing_code as the foreign key value, as it's
>   the only common data that can associate the two models."*

I would suggest resolving this as part of your CSV importer.
As you import each record, do a find for an appointment record that has a matching 'writing code' and then save the record to include the appointment id.

Something like this:

```
# Inside your CSV importer script

csv_rows.each do |row|
  policy = Policy.new
  policy.appointment_id = Appointment.find(writing_code: row.writing_code).id
  # more code here..
  policy.save
end
```

Comment: I agree that this would be the conventional way of designing this association.  Unfortunately, because this app needs to accommodate a legacy system, I'm not sure that's a feasible option.  In this example, I have policy data that will be uploaded from a legacy system via .csv file.  This data will have no knowledge of the appointment_id, which is why I need to use the writing_code as the foreign key value, as it's the only common data that can associate the two models. I'd love to keep this "conventional", but I don't see how I can accomplish this... thanks for your thoughts

Comment: Interesting solution.. I'll need to dig into this option a bit deeper to determine if this would accommodate all scenarios.  Thanks for the alternative suggestion @evolve